# How to have a generic function to get the current dir and file name in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking to see if I can have a generic function added at the beginning of every .sh file to tell me the dir and file. The problem is that this one tells me the root, but not every file info...

file: file.sh

```
function file_init() {
  script="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
  source="$(cd "$(dirname "${script_path}")" && pwd)"
 }
```

usage in main.sh:

```
. file.sh 
file_init
```

Comment: Does your distro have `realpath`?

Comment: What should the result of the function be? Should it set `script=file.sh` or `script=main.sh`? `is that this one tells me the root, but not every file info` What does that mean? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

To get the full path, simply like this:

```
readlink -f <file or dir>
```

or if available:

```
realpath <file or dir>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is script file name and the directory where the script is,

file.sh

```
script_name="$(basename "$1")"
script_dir="$(cd "$(dirname "$1")" && echo "$PWD")"
```

main.sh

```
. file.sh "$BASH_SOURCE"
# Now you can access $script_name and $script_dir
```